# Update syntax SQLite in ionic 2

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic2

I have this script for update my SQLite table,
I don't know why it doesn't work I have edited my query script but still doesn't work

```
try{
    this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'msc.db',
    location: 'default'
  })
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
     db.executeSql('update member set email = '+email+', phone= '+phone+'',{})
      .then(() => console.log('Truncate Table Success'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  })
}catch(err){
  alert(err)
}
```

Comment: are you updating all the rows of the table? what are you intending to do update? Also what does doesnt work mean? any errors?

Comment: yes it only has one row, i got there is not error,, the error it should be appear in alert cz i use the try catch, but there is not error i got

Comment: its better if you had a where condition to specify the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use a parameterized query. Check sample [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#update-rows-in-the-database-). You are using Cordova-sqlite-storage with the ionic-native SQLite.

```
try{
    this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'msc.db',
    location: 'default'
  })
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

     db.executeSql('update member set email = ?, phone= ?',[email,phone])
      .then(() => console.log('Truncate Table Success'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  })
}catch(err){
  alert(err)
}
```